# created schedule cron job main class as runnable jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduler, runnable, cronexpression

```
- i have written ScheduleClass which call HelloJob class every 5 seconds.
```

`

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;



public class ScheduleClass {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {   
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
                .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
                .withSchedule(
                        CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?"))
                .build();

        //schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}


public class HelloJob implements Job
 {
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
  throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");    
  }
}

`
```

- in my IDE(SpringToolSuite) given File-->Export-->selecting Runnable JAR File-->Lunch Configuration (main class ) & Export destination(my local path)-->Finsh
- i got jar file in local path.
- from cmd c:\mypath>java -jar ScheduleClassTest.jar
- only one time executed.
- need to run every 5seconds.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: thanks Albert : from cmd i run jar file its excuted only one time, i want its HelloJob class executs every 10 sconds.

Comment: I run and works perfectly (on eclipse). Every 10 seconds prints "Hello Quartz!". Does it run in your IDE before creating jar?

Comment: Before creating jar & in IDE its working fine. but when i deployment or run other machines its should be run every 10 seconds(only one time its runned).

Comment: i have written code simle created txt file based on server time insteadof print "Hello Quartz!"., then its creating one time file creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this should be a comment, but can't format there so I post it as an answer.

Don't know how `SpringToolSuite` works or create jars. I did by myself and works as expected:

- **Compilation:** I use same code than you (adding a `Date` with format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` in `HelloJob` class). Compiled and run using `Oracle JDK 1.6` with `quartz 2.2`

  ```
  javac -cp c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar;log4j-1.2.16.jar;quartz-2.2.1.jar;quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar;slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;. ScheduleClass.java 
  javac -cp c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar;log4j-1.2.16.jar;quartz-2.2.1.jar;quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar;slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;. HelloJob.java
  ```
- **Create jar:**

  ```
  jar -cf sched.jar ScheduleClass.class HelloJob.class
  ```

  Here you can add an especific `MANIFEST` file indicating its `Main-Class` entry (I didn't do, but it should work as well)

  It contains:

  ```
  unzip -l sched.jar
  ```

  > Archive:  sched.jar 
  >   META-INF/ 
  >   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
  >   ScheduleClass.class 
  >   HelloJob.class
- **Running**

  ```
  java -cp c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar;log4j-1.2.16.jar;quartz-2.2.1.jar;quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar;slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;sched.jar ScheduleClass
  ```
- **Output**

  > log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory). 
  >   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
  >   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info. 
  >   2015-04-16 13:26:20.17 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:26:30.2 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:26:40.3 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:26:50.3 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:27:00.4 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:27:10.5 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:27:20.21 - Hello Quartz! 
  >   2015-04-16 13:27:30.6 - Hello Quartz!

It continues until CTRL+C is pressed

You see your code is correct. Maybe something is wrong in the way your jar is created. Take a look at it, or try to compile by yourself (if possible) as I did.

Sorry for not being more helpful, but I see nothing wrong.